# Running spring boot app over apache2 and serving php content

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have my spring boot application running over apache using proxy. It is also running over a secure connection. 
Apache virtualhost config is:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
```

I want to server static content in a folder /gettweets, so that when a user access https://myurl/gettweet the index php file will be called.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite with the P flag instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gettweet/.*$ /gettweet/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost:8443/$1 [L,P,QSA]
```